# Injecting arguments in scrapy's pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a custom pipeline with some arguments that i need to inject in the constructor, like:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, some_argument):
        self.some_argument = some_argument
...
```

The script (let's call it run_crawler.py) from where I start the crawling process it's:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(SomeCrawler)
process.crawl(AnotherCrawler)
...
process.start()
```

And in settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'crawler.pipelines.SomePipeline': 100,
    'crawler.pipelines.MyPipeline': 300
}
```

I guess this is a silly question but i've been unable to find in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) how to instantiate MyPipeline with custom arguments. Could someone plz point me in the right direction?

In particular, i don't know how should (or if i should at all) modify run_crawler.py to instantiate the custom argument for MyPipeline, i'm guessing it should be something like:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(SomeCrawler)
process.crawl(AnotherCrawler)
...
some_argument = ... # instantiate my custom argument
# this is made up, it's what i've been unable to find how to do properly
my_pipeline = MyPipeline(some_argument)
process.pipelines.append(my_pipeline, ...)

process.start()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question, but it sounds like overwriting the constructor, calling `super` and modifying the parameters you need could solve your problem.

Comment: @FernandoCezar the thing is that in settings.py i just declare the pipelines, but is scrapy who does the instantiation. i don't know where i can specify the dependencies for MyPipeline

Comment: Create a class inheriting from the one you're using, and tell scrapy to use the one you created. So you can overwrite the constructor on that class.

Comment: @FernandoCezar if i understand correctly, that would be to extend the constructor and add arguments. what i don't know how to do is inject the arguments from the script to the pipeline. i'll edit the question to clarify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scrapy `from_crawler` method.
The scrapy docs have a good [description](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#from_crawler) and [example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb):

```
class MongoPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'scrapy_items'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )
```

"*If present, this classmethod is called to create a pipeline instance from a Crawler. It must return a new instance of the pipeline.*"

This way you can create new instance of the pipeline depend of the crawler or spider settings.