# pass arguments to __init__ for pipelines in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I know there is a way to do this using the following example, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117659/injecting-arguments-in-scrapys-pipeline) (also based on [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)):

```
class MongoPipeline(object):

collection_name = 'scrapy_items'

def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
    self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
    self.mongo_db = mongo_db

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(
        mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
    )
```

However as far as I know, this takes those values from a settings file. In my case, I must use it as an argument, since it is an arbitrary string provided by the user, so it won't be in any file.

This situation is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513707/using-arguments-in-scrapy-pipeline-on-init/27513877#comment86284761_27513877). Nevertheless I also need to use the argument during the `__init__` method since my pipeline is inheriting from another arbitrary class which needs this parameter, so the workaround provided for this second question (which was just to pass arguments inside the spider), but this won't work for me (since I need it in the `__init__`).

To clarify, my situation is the following:

```
class Foo():
    # this class is not a pipelines, 
    # it is just an arbitrary class which manages the connections with the databases
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        self.foo=foo

class MyPipieline(Foo):
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        Foo.__init__(foo)
```

Where foo is a string provided by the user, so it can't be read from a file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify: the foo parameter is provided by the user at the invocation of the script, so my `main` is something like that:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My main script')
# Add arguments
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', type=str, required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

foo = args.foo
# Here I have the foo value I want to use in pipeline's __init__

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you've written? Does `crawler.settings` not have the values yet at the time it calls your `from_crawler`? Is there some syntax error or other exception that you haven't shown us? Do you not know how to super the `__init__` in your first example even though you did it in the second one? …? We need a [mcve], including a clear description of what's not working.

Comment: @abarnert I can't provide a minimal complete verifiable example since I don't know how to do what I want to do, and that is what I am asking: How can I pass arguments to `__init__` method in `MyPipeline` **without** using the `@classmehod def from_crawler` as suggested in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: Why can’t you use the `from_crawler` method? When it does `cls(args)`, that will call `cls.__init__` with the `self` and those same `args`, which can then super the base class `__init__` with whatever args it wants, which seems to be exactly what you’re saying you don’t know how to do, so... what’s wrong with that?

Comment: If you’re asking how to get another argument passed in, the question is: where is that value supposed to come from? A “string provided by the user” has to be provided somewhere. Is the user providing it on the command line? In response to an `input()` at startup? By modifying the source? By thinking about it real hard and hoping the computer guesses it? If you can show where it comes from and where it’s stored, we can probably show you how to use it here, but if you can’t, nobody can help.

Comment: I'm taking `foo` parameter from command line, I will edit my question to clarify this point. I'm still thinking about how should I use the `from_crawler`

Comment: OK, if you can’t pass `foo` through the crawler to get it passed in to the `from_crawler` method, you have to put it somewhere that method can find it. For example, if you do `crawler.cmd_args = args`, your method can use `crawler.cmd_args.foo`. (That may not be the best design—you have to make sure that crawlers never have a `cmd_args`, and that they allow new attributes to be added, etc.; it’s just an example of something both parts of your code have access to.)

Comment: thanks @abarnert 
I'm not sure if I didn't explained my self or if I didn't get what you said, but I end up getting the arguments with `from_crawler` method I used `foo=crawler.spider.foo`

Comment: You _can_ write a MCVE for this problem: the simplest program that sets `foo` and kicks off the crawler, and also registers a trivial pipeline class and gets the pipeline created by the crawler. Of course that program will not get `foo` passed in anywhere—but that's exactly the problem you're trying to demonstrate. So just add `# I need to use foo here, but I don't have it and don't know where to get it from`, and you've got an MCVE. Then someone can just show you how to get `foo` from one part of your program to the other, without having to guess that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is provided by the user it will probably be passed as a attribute to the `spider` instance, right?

In that case, you will have to postpone the Foo instantiation to a bit later:

```
class Foo:
    # Class logic

class MyPipieline():

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a dictionary of spiders to foos
        self.foos = {}

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.foos[spider.name] = Foo.__init__(spider.foo)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.foos[spider.name].close() # If needed
```

The `self.foos` dictionary is needed because you may have different spiders with different `foo` attributes running simultaning.

Comment: I think it works but it losts the benefits of inheriting from `Foo`